# How can I call a non-static JFrame method inside a static method?

Tags: java, swing, static, jframe, non-static

My goal: Create a `JFrame` with a button that changes the location inside the frame when clicked.

For that, I need the height and width of the frame.

The error I get and do not fully understand:

```java
Fangmich.java:58:24: error: non-static method getWidth() cannot be referenced from a static context
    int maxX = Fangmich.getWidth() - Button1.getWidth();
                       ^
Fangmich.java:59:24: error: non-static method getHeight() cannot be referenced from a static context
    int maxY = Fangmich.getHeight() - Button1.getHeight();
                       ^
2 errors
```

I know the difference between static and non-static, but I can not think out a solution to store attributes of my JFrame object as variables inside my Button event. My misstake is super obviously for sure and I'm just blind.

This is my code. I'm sry, my school forces me to use Java Editor. "Fangmich" is the JFrame object.

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class Fangmich extends JFrame {
  // Anfang Attribute
  private JButton Button1 = new JButton();
  // Ende Attribute
  
  public Fangmich() { 
    // Frame-Initialisierung
    super();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    int frameWidth = 300; 
    int frameHeight = 300;
    setSize(frameWidth, frameHeight);
    Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int x = (d.width - getSize().width) / 2;
    int y = (d.height - getSize().height) / 2;
    setLocation(x, y);
    setTitle("Fangmich");
    setResizable(true);
    Container cp = getContentPane();
    cp.setLayout(null);
    // Anfang Komponenten
    
    Button1.setBounds(0, 0, 73, 41);
    Button1.setText("Fang mich!");
    Button1.setMargin(new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2));
    Button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { 
        Button1_ActionPerformed(evt);
      }
    });
    cp.add(Button1);
    // Ende Komponenten
    
    setVisible(true);
  } // end of public Fangmich

  // Anfang Methoden
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Fangmich();
    
  } // end of main
  
  public void Button1_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    
    Random Xrand = new Random();
    Random Yrand = new Random();
    
    int maxX = Fangmich.getWidth() - Button1.getWidth();
    int maxY = Fangmich.getHeight() - Button1.getHeight();

    int xLocation = Xrand.nextInt(maxX);
    int yLocation = Yrand.nextInt(maxY);
    
    Button1.setLocation(xLocation, yLocation);
    
  } // end of Button1_ActionPerformed

  // Ende Methoden
} // end of class Fangmich
```

EDIT: thx for trying to help me, it just proves again that I should not use the pre-build `JFrame` in Java Editor and just write frames myself. Even if it's more work. I'm forced to use it.

Comment: The answer is _usually_ that whatever you have as static shouldn't be.

Comment: Typically the best method would be to call create the frame in a new class then you can make the JFrame a private within that class. If you need to access the frame from another class you can make a getFrame() function and return the JFrame. You shouldn't make the JFrame a static.

Also, there is no reason for you to be extending the JFrame, you clearly arn't overriding anything within the JFrame.

https://pastebin.com/NBV2pLv7

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Method names should NOT start with an upper case character. Learn by example from whatever text book or tutorial you are using. Don't use a null layout and setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Start by reading the [Swing Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html)  for Swing basics.